# Why send my Arduino sometime Hex and sometimes the wrong?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

Hi i have an Arduino mega 2560 i send data from the Arduino over USB to PC. That works when i test a simple Serial.print("Hello"); but that is not that what i need. I send a timestamp as a longe Value and the databyte as a short Value. When i send the timestamp as BIN like that:

```
      //Initialisisation

const int RX = 0;
const int TX = 1;
const int RX1 = 19;
const int TX1 = 18;
unsigned long currentMillis;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(RX, INPUT);   //Readpin for USB
  pinMode(TX, OUTPUT);  //Writepin for USB
  pinMode(RX1, INPUT);  //Readpin for bus
  pinMode(TX1, OUTPUT); //Writepin for für bus

  Serial.begin(38400);   //open interface for USB
  Serial1.begin(4800);   //open interface for bus

  while (!Serial & !Serial1 &! Serial2)
  {
    ;//wait for serial port connect.
  }
}

void loop()
{
  //Ask if the timestamp over 8 hours, when yes,
  //send the time to the pc and reset currentMillis.
  currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis >= 28800000)  //milli() 8 hours is a 4 byte  timestamp 28.800.000 millisec.
  {
    unsigned long timestamp = currentMillis;
    sendBinaryTime(timestamp);
    currentMillis = 0;
  }//end if

  //if the businterface available, read a byte
  //and send it with the timestamp to the PC.
  //If the businterface not available send an error.
  //short incomingByte = Serial1.read();
  //sendBinaryValue(incomingByte);
  if(Serial1.available()>0) //if the bus (serial1) available?
    {
      short incomingByte = Serial1.read(); //read the next byte from _rx_buffer
      sendBinaryValue(incomingByte);
      sendBinaryTime(currentMillis);   //sendBinary send a long over the bus
    }//end if 
}//end Loop()


//Methods for sending long values

void sendBinaryValue(short incomingByte)
  {
    int temp = (incomingByte & 0xFF00)>>8;
    Serial.println(temp, HEX);
    temp = (incomingByte & 0x00FF);
    Serial.println(temp, HEX);
    return;
  }

void sendBinaryTime(unsigned long currentMillis)//send milliseconds after every byte
{
  int temp = (currentMillis & 0xFF000000)>>24; //send 16 bit of the low value
  Serial.print(temp, BIN);
  temp = (currentMillis & 0x00FF0000)>>16;      //send 16 bit of the high value
  Serial.print(temp, BIN);
  temp = (currentMillis & 0x0000FF00)>>8;
  Serial.print(temp, BIN);
  temp = (currentMillis & 0x000000FF);
  Serial.print(temp, BIN);
  return;
}
```

All is fine i haven´t any error. But i want the timestamp as DEC so i have changed the code to:

```
       void sendBinaryValue(short incomingByte)
 {
   int temp = (incomingByte & 0xFF00)>>8;
   Serial.println(temp, HEX);
   temp = (incomingByte & 0x00FF);
   Serial.println(temp, HEX);
   return;
 }

void sendBinaryTime(unsigned long currentMillis)
{
 int temp = (currentMillis & 0xFF000000)>>24;
 Serial.print(temp, DEC);
 temp = (currentMillis & 0x00FF0000)>>16;
 Serial.print(temp, DEC);
 temp = (currentMillis & 0x0000FF00)>>8;
 Serial.print(temp, DEC);
 temp = (currentMillis & 0x000000FF);
 Serial.print(temp, DEC);
 return;
}
```

Now when i look on the serial monitor i get an error.
Here you can see it:

[image]

I send an A as ASCII sign that must be Hex 41 and i receive a Hex 5 but why? When i send the timestamp as BIN i get the 41 and haven´t any problem.

I hope someone can help me with friendly wishes sniffi

Comment: Please, post a testable code, with `setup()` and `loop()`, so we can reproduce your problem. I tried the obvious and got “41”, as expected, which proves you have a problem in a piece of code you are not showing to us. How do you expect us to help you with that?

Comment: I have fix it, i think perhapes it is an already known problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found several problems with your program, although they may not
be related with your primary problem:

```c++
while (!Serial & !Serial1 &! Serial2)
```

You mean `while (!Serial || !Serial1 || !Serial2)`, although this is
only useful with virtual serial ports, like on the Leonardo. On the
mega, all of these ports are real hardware ports.

```c++
void sendBinaryValue(short incomingByte)
```

The way you name the parameter is misleading: a `short` is not a byte,
it's two bytes.

```c++
int temp = (incomingByte & 0xFF00)>>8;
```

You are bit-shifting a signed number, which is going to do a sign
extension. This is probably not what you want.

```c++
Serial.print(temp, DEC);
```

You are printing several numbers one after the other with no separator.
This is going to cause ambiguities: you cannot know whether "345" means
"3 45" or "34 5".

Finally, I don't get the purpose of your functions. Why don't you just
print the numbers like this?

```c++
Serial.println(incomingByte, HEX);
Serial.println(currentMillis);
```

Comment: Ok i have delete the `while(!Serial & !Serial1 & !Serial2)` . I have changed the ringbuffer to 16bit (my short) because i want handle flags at the high byte. Can i send a short and a long over Serial.print?

Comment: Yes, you can `print()` numbers from 8 to 32 bits, signed or unsigned.

Comment: Ok i have change all now the bug is fixed thanks for all